# Unexpected iterator behavior as a member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++17

I'm having trouble with iterators:

```cpp
class Foo {
 private:
  std::istream_iterator<char> it_;

 public:
  Foo(std::string filepath) {
    std::ifstream file(filepath);
    it_ = std::istream_iterator<char>(file);
  }

  char Next() {
    char c = *it_;
    it_++;
    return c;
  }

  bool HasNext() { return it_ != std::istream_iterator<char>(); }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo("../input.txt");

  while (foo.HasNext()) {
    std::cout << foo.Next();
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The file `input.txt` is just `Hello, world!`.

But when I run this, it only prints `H`. It seems to have something to do with storing the iterator as a member variable?

Comment: In the `Foo` constructor, how long is the life-time of the `file` you open? What do you think happens with the iterator using the file, when the underlying stream object gets destructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
Foo(std::string filepath) {
    std::ifstream file(filepath);
    it_ = std::istream_iterator<char>(file);
}
```

You store an iterator to `file`. Once this constructor returns `file`s destructor is called and all iterators to the `ifstream` become invalid. It is similar to using a pointer to a no longer existing object. You need a `ifstream` to read from, the iterator just refers to contents that can be extracted from the file, but if the file is gone you cannot extract from it. Store the `ifstream` as member too.

You can read the first character, because already on construction of the `std::istream_iterator` the first character is extracted from the file.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Can you please give an example of setting the ifstream as a member? I tried the obvious way and got a compiler error `'operator=' is a private member of 'std::ios_base'`.

Comment: @SilverSlash the "obvious" way is to use the member initializer list to initialize members.

Comment: doesn't resolve it

Comment: @SilverSlash https://godbolt.org/z/E13GG7rr7. Btw please dont remove the includes from code you post.

Comment: thanks, that works. Only one strange thing, the ' ' in my 'Hello, world' doesn't get printed. Any idea why?

Comment: @SilverSlash what '' ? What is the content of the file? In the question you write it would be just `Hello, World!`

Comment: @SilverSlash do you mean the space? Read the notes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator